# Mushrooms in my lawn

Tags: grass

Why do I have mushrooms popping up in my yard?  I had my lawn professionally aerated and overseeded in early spring and now I am seeing mushrooms throughout the lawn.

Comment: Sorry I meant overseeded, sometimes I hate auto correct!

Comment: FYI, I edited your post to fix the spelling.

Comment: They may be edible; if they consistently come back, it gives you time to check them out.  For several years I collected Shaggy Manes from lawns in IN.  The neighbors were glad to see them removed.

Comment: do you have pictures of the mushrooms? they may be edible mushrooms.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I wouldn't worry about the mushrooms. Their appearance likely doesn't have anything to do with the lawn treatments you did, fungal spores are just in the environment & will grow where they find suitable habitat.

If they bother you, you could pick them as they appear & toss them in the compost. Alternately, you could apply fungicide to the lawn, but I personally would not, as fungus (especially their underground network of mycellium) are actually part of a healthy environment.